# How do I regain ownership over a Google Developer Console project when the current owner has left the company?

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console

### The background

- I added an employee to a Google Project in Developer Console a while back. For reasons unclear to me now, I added him as an Owner.
- I was then relegated to Editor role. He left the company and his GSuite account was deleted.
- We have used the service credentials for the project throughout many client accounts so recreating the project isn't an option
- We have recreated his email account, but there seems to be no way of resending an invite from the Google Project.
- The project belongs to no organisation (again, my mistake!)

### The problem

I need to become the owner of the project again so I can remove him. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have been thru this before for customers. 1) If it is your credit (or the company's credit card) that has been processing the billing this will be easier. If it was the previous employee's credit card, pull together expense reports and cancelled checks proving payment. 2) Write a letter explaining the situation and have it notorized at your bank. 3) Make photocopies of your ID. 4) Make copies of the company documents (business license, incorporation, current bank statement). If you are detailed and organized and your documents can be easily verified, you should be able to get control.

Comment: The key is to remove all risk to Google (AWS, Azure, etc.) so that they can transfer control to you. The best way is thru documents that are backed by legal authorities (notorized letter, photocopies of ID, business license, etc.). I would also include contact information for the employee that left the company.

Comment: Thanks John. This sounds like a lot of work, so we're going to create a new project and migrate all clients across to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet it to restore the GSuite account and assign it a new password and then use it directly. Outside of recovering the account there are no alternatives other than contacting GCP Support. To speed up the process provide as much documentation as possible to show that the previous owner no longer exists.

Not being in your organization may be a real hassle. Do they use the same associated billing accounts?

Imagine how this looks for GCP, a member on a project wants to be owner and they can't contact the original owner to get confirmation. If they make you the owner they are then responsible if you remove the original owner who did not actually want to make you an owner. They will likely link you to the [account recover page](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620?hl=en), with a statement that they're not able to do it. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the details FridayPush. You make many great points here. We're going to create a brand new project and ditch the old one. Looks like it isn't easily recoverable, especially as all the billing etc is in my name. Lesson learned!